# Pop-up window asking to close the tab in sharepoint where yammer is integrated

Tags: sharepoint, browser, yammer

I have added Yammer script in Sharepoint but I am getting Pop-up window asking to close the tab in Internet explorer:

Code section :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script> 

<div id='embedded-feed' style='height:100%;width:100%;'/>

<script type="text/javascript" >
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  'network': 'xxx.com',
  'feedType': 'group',
  'feedId': 1111,
  'config': {
    'use_sso': true,
    'header': false,
    'footer': false,
    'showOpenGraphPreview': false,
    'defaultToCanonical': false,
    'hideNetworkName': false
  },
  'container': '#embedded-feed'
});

</script>
```

I have added the code into Sharepoint script editor and getting the mentioned pop-up window asking to close the tab:

> The webpage you are viewing is trying to close tab. Do you want to close this tab?

[image]

Can you help me with finding the problem?